# Where can I find hillmen?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I've just hit level 30 and want to complete the Race of Man deed "Enmity of the Hillmen" and get myself a nice new racial trait.

Unfortunately, I've not come across a hillman yet in my travels.

Whereabouts can I find Hillmen and, for a bonus, where can I find the *lowest-levelled* Hillmen to make my life a bit easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hillmen can be found in:

- Agamaur (Lone-Lands)
- Garth Agarwen (Lone-Lands)
- **East of Estedlin** (North Downs)
- Fassach-Falroid (Angmar)
- South Trollshaws (Trollshaws)
- **Evendim** -- These are around level 36, and are called Gauredain. They can be found all over
- Hillmen are also found in Forochel, Dunland, and Eregion.

You can see [this page](http://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Hill-men) for information about the various Hill-men in LOTRO.

Also, see if you can find a group who is also grinding Hill-men, it will make things a lot faster!

Comment: I just found, in Garth Agarwn, some level ~30 Hillmen who are NOT Elites. They're probably the lowest-level ones, but this is a comprehensive list. Actually, whoops, some of them ARE elites. Better watch out...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://lotro.mmorsel.com/2010/01/race-of-man-traits.html), you should look in Amagaur in the Lone-Lands or Nan Amlug East in the North Downs. It suggests grouping, so you might not want to go it alone.

Comment: Yeah... I just fought my way there and they're Elites. Oh well!

Answer (score -1):

You can find some at the Misty Mountains at The Bitter Stair. Those also drop Rivendell rep items & mathoms.